# ASP.NET 5 strongly typed configuration JSON format

Tags: asp.net, json, configuration

I am trying to leverage the new ASP.NET 5 configuration builder for the following objects. Does anyone know the JSON syntax for array type fields?

```
public class ProjectConfiguration
{
    public ProjectSubfolder[] ProjectSubfolders { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectSubfolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ProjectPermission[] ProjectPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectPermission
{
    public string Identity { get; set; }

    public FileSystemRights FileSystemRights { get; set; }

    public InheritanceFlags InheritanceFlags { get; set; }

    public PropagationFlags PropagationFlags { get; set; }

    public AccessControlType AccessControlType { get; set; }
}
```

The json I am using which fails to populate the ProjectConfiguration.ProjectSubfolders array looks like:

```
{
    "ProjectConfiguration": {
        "ProjectSubfolders": [
            {
                "Name": "MyName",
                "ProjectPermissions": [
                    {
                        "Identity": "Domain\\ShortId",
                        "FileSystemRights": "FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories",
                        "InheritanceFlags": "InheritanceFlags.None",
                        "PropagationFlags": "PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit",
                        "AccessControlType": "AccessControlType.Allow"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, it seems that "ProjectSubfolders" key populates with any number of objects including their "Name" key but what never populates is "ProjectPermissions"? The syntax between the working "ProjectSubfolders" array and the none working "ProjectPermissions" array is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Epic self fail, when converting from the original XML serializer based implementation, the copy/paste work left the System.Security.AccessControl type names prefixed on the values.

```
"FileSystemRights": "FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories"
```

should have been

```
"FileSystemRights": "CreateDirectories"
```